# Query for generate a tree in UI

Tags: mysql, database

Problem:

A student has mother, father, elder sister and elder brother. If the student's parents occupation is teacher, the I want to generate tree in UI by getting data from backend table. For this, I have created a table to store student information like, student id(pk), name of student, gender, address, father,mother, father_occupation, mother_occupation, etc., Also I added one option (checkbox) in UI to find student's relative occupation is teacher or not. If checkbox is true, then occupation column will be update a value true or 1.

For this, one table is enough or more than one table needed? Also how the query should if all in one table and how the query should be if need to maintain in separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of options for this schema, but for future scale, I would go with a hierarchy type table, and then attribute table(s) for the folks involved in the hierarchy. This would allow you to track student/teacher relationships (with the right attributes) within the same structure.

Table1 would hold your hierarchical information, which would be the relationships between your people:

```
id | parent_id | other_relationship_attributes
```

Table2 would hold information about the individual:

```
id | occupation | gender | etc..
```

You can then write queries that can traverse your hierarchy and pull relevant info from the individuals table.

If your student info is very different then your parent info (probably), then that second table would make sense to break up into two tables. 1 for your student and one for the parents.

An example of what this might look like in SQL, answering the question "Show me all students where their parents are teachers:

```
SELECT
    student.id,
    student.name,
    CASE WHEN student.gender = 'F' THEN 'Daughter' ELSE 'Son' END as child_relationship
    parent.id,
    parent.name,
    parent.occupation,
    CASE WHEN parent.gender = 'M' Then 'Father' ELSE 'Mother End as parent_relationship
FROM
    person as student
    INNER JOIN hier on student.id = hier.id
    INNER JOIN person as parent on hier.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE
    parent.occupation = 'Teacher'
```

Comment: Sorry. I am new to DB. Here, how we relate table1 and table2. Can u pls explain me with the table structure? Thanks.

Comment: I've added an example of what that structure might look like in SQL to show the relationships. Beyond that, if you are still struggling with how this looks or why it might look this way, you might want to just try it out in real life (check out sqlfiddle.com if you don't have access to a DB to play with). You might want to read up on basic SQL and Relational DB schema.